# PHP: Delete checked rows

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I will have to mention first that I have searched for a Google and stackoverflow and anywhere else, as well as tried to use scripts given in forums and write my own ones, but nothing worked for me. I am completely stuck.

So, all I try to do is to write a script that will delete checked rows from MySQL table. Here is my HTML written inside of a PHP file:

```
<tr class="noP">
  <td class="check"><input class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row["PID"].'"/></td>
  <td class="id">'.$row['PID'].'</th>
  <td>'.$row["name"].'</th>
  <td>'.$row["surname"].'</th>
  <td>'.$row["pcode"].'</th>
  <td class="address">'.$row["address"].'</th>
  <td class="email">'.$row["email"].'</th>
  <td>'.$row["phone"].'</th>
  <td class="education">'.$row["education"].'</th>
  <td class="remarks">'.$row["remarks"].'</th>
</tr>
```

for here `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qParts);`, so this array is just a collector of field values from MySQL DB.

Basically, all I try to do is just a table with all the participants listed with ability to delete selected ones.

I would highly appreciate any help provided. Thank you!

Comment: Can you check what will happen with my super awesome remark: `$row["remarks"] = '<script>alert("xss yo");</script>';`

Comment: If I did not have something like mysql_real_escape_string() and similar, it would gave me the simple alert message. Very funny

Comment: @ArtemUshakov - you want `htmlspecialchars()` for that.

Comment: uhhhm yeah. don't use mres for that....

Comment: Yes, I guess I have specialchars(). It all is in my function in another file, so I don't really remember :)

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

```
foreach($_REQUEST['checkbox'] as $val)
    $delIds = intval($val);

$delSql = implode($delIds, ",");

mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE PID IN ($delSql)");
```

So, that takes your input array from `$_GET`/`$_POST`, sanitises it (a little), then implodes it to get a list of IDs (e.g. 5, 7, 9, 13). It then feeds that into an SQL statement, matching on those IDs using the `IN` operator.

Note that you should do this using prepared statements or similar. It's been a while though, so I can't write them off-hand, but this should give you the gist of it.

To do this using PDO, have a look here. It's a bit more complex, since you need to dynamically create the placeholders, but it should then work the same.

[Reference - frequently asked questions about PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991146)

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help you out. I had the same issue during my semester project. The problem can be solved using HTML and PHP alone.

I am assuming that PID is the primary key in your table. The trick here is to put the entire table in a form so that it looks like this:

```
      <form action="/*NAME OF THIS PAGE HERE*/.php" method="POST">

                       <?php

     if(isset($_POST['delete']))   //THE NAME OF THE BUTTON IS delete. 
    {
       foreach ($_POST["checkbox"] as $id){
       $de1 = "DELETE FROM //table-name WHERE PID='$id'";
       if(mysqli_query($conn, $de1))
       echo "<b>Deletion Successful. </b>";
       else
       echo "ERROR: Could not execute";
       }
    }
        if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
            echo"<b>Please make a selection to complete this operation.</b>";
        }

    ?>
    </br>


<!-- below you will see that I had placed an image as the delete button and stated its styles -->

                              <button type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" style="float:right;border:none; background:none;">
                              <img style="width:55px; height:55px;margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:6px; float:left;" src="images/del.png">
                              </button>


                                    <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>PID</th>
                                        <th>NAME</th>
                                        <th>SURNAME</th>
                                        <!--REST OF THE TABLE HEADINGS HERE -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php $fqn="SELECT * FROM //table-name here;
                                    $fqn_run=mysqli_query($conn,$fqn);
                                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fqn_run)):?>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="noP">
  <td class="check"><input class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row["PID"];?>"></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['PID'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["surname"];?></td>
  <!-- REST OF THE ROWS HERE -->
</tr><?php endwhile;?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
    </div>
    </div>      

    </form>
```

Hope this helps you.